# unreferenced .ts file in project's root "is not under root dir"

Tags: typescript

I've got a loose utility script `name.ts` lying in the project's root dir. I invoke it with `ts-node` when needed. This script is not referenced anywhere in the actual source.

The actual source of my program is under `src`.

Whenever I try to run `tsc` (in `tsconfig.json`, `rootDir` is set to `./src`), it throws:

```
error TS6059: File '/home/rijndael/projects/mc/js/lua/generate.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/home/rijndael/projects/mc/js/lua/scripts-ts'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), `rootDir` is only used for the directory structure when using `outDir`. What you need is to tell TypeScript which files to include (or exclude) by using the `include` or `exclude` config option respectively.

In your case you could either add `include: ['src/**/*']` to only use files in your source directoy, or exclude your scripts with `exclude: ['utilities/**/*']` (replace 'utilities' by your scripts folder).

An example tsconfig could then look like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    // your compile options
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"], // only include your src directory
  "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts"] // exclude tests and add scripts if you have any in "src/"
}
```

`include` works like a whitelist. Only files that match any of the glob pattern here is included in your build. `exclude` works like a blacklist. Files that match any of the glob pattern here will be excluded from your build (even if matched by `include`).

Comment: I've got both `rootDir` and `outDir`. Nevertheless, good answer, I've solved it with `exclude`.

Comment: Glad it helped you :) Btw. `rootDir` does **not** tell TypeScript what files to include in your build (even with `outDir`). It only tells it what the folder structure should look like **if** you use `outDir` and has no effect otherwise.